# How can I get plotly to ignore NaNs without removing them from the dataframe

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have the following code that produces a bar plot, but includes all NaN's in my dataframe as well. Is it possible to have plotly ignore them when plotting?

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=TEU.index,
                    y= TEU[TEU.columns[0]]))
updatemenu = []
buttons = []

for col in TEU.columns:
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                       label=col,
                       args=[{'y':[TEU[col]],
                             'x':[TEU.index],
                             'type':'bar'}, [0]],
                       )
                  )

updatemenu = []
menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True

fig.update_layout(xaxis={'categoryorder': 'total descending'})

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```